Excel cannot format numbers in result string
It seemed to be an easy work, but I can't get it done:
Given:
I4: 0.32
E4: 12
=Round(I4*2;2) & "/pc  //  " & Round(I4*2*E4;2) & "/unit"

gives the result string "0.64 /pc  //  7.68 /unit"
I want to format the result into
"€ 0.64 /pc  //  € 7.68 /unit"

I tried to use TEXT() but in any worksheet TEXT() does not work!
Simple:  =TEXT(I4;"00")  even gives #NAME
Same as =TEXT(I4;"€ #.##0,00") which should give "€ 0,32".
So =TEXT(Round(I4*2;2);"€ #.##0,00 /pc") & "  //  " & TEXT(Round(I4*2*E4;2); & ""€ #.##0,00 / unit")  does not work and gives #VALUE.
Thanks your help.

TEXT function - Microsoft Support
We could use full format code (specifying postive;negative;zero and suffix), also make use of automatic rounding:
=TEXT(I4*2, "[$€-x-euro2] #,##0.00 "" /pc"";;;") & " // "
& TEXT(I4*2*E4,"[$€-x-euro2] #,##0.00 "" /unit"";;;")

But defining the format codes in Name Manager will make them easy use and maintain.

Please change , etc. to match your regional settings.

Try using the following formula:


=TEXTJOIN(" // ",,TEXT(ROUND(I4*2*HSTACK(1,E4),2),{"€ 0.00 \/pc","€ 0.00 \/u\n\i\t"}))


You might need to change the list separators based on your locale settings aka regional settings.

If you don't have access to HSTACK() then:
=TEXT(ROUND(I4*2,2),"€ 0.00 \/pc")
 &" // "&
 TEXT(ROUND(I4*2*E4,2),"€ 0.00 \/u\n\i\t")


Just for suggestions, this is what I usually do, if my custom formatting are not working, then i place them in a different cells, to find the root cause, and then select the region of custom formatting and hit F9 function key:


Posted here on usage of Escape Characters --> Check Here



In German Versions:
Option One:
=TEXT(RUNDEN(I4*2;2);"€ #,##0.00 \/pc")
 &" // "&
 TEXT(RUNDEN(I4*2*E4;2);"€ #,##0.00 \/u\n\i\t")


Option Two:
=TEXTVERKETTEN(" // ";;TEXT(RUNDEN(I4*2*HSTACK(1;E4);2);{"€ #,##0.00 \/pc";"€ #,##0.00 \/u\n\i\t"}))


Option Three:
=TEXT(RUNDEN(I4*2; 2); "€ #,##0.00") & " /pc // " & TEXT(RUNDEN(I4*2*E4; 2); "€ #,##0.00") & " /unit"



Thanks your proposals, but NOTHING works! Problem could be that TEXT does not work, even with a very simple useage such as =TEXT(5;"00") for example. Any idea why??

@Mak check your local settings. Certainly it might be its TEKST() and not TEXT() for you. Functions vary with versions of languages used. Are you using Excel in English version? And when you say NOTHING works could you show me a screenshot with the formula bar and error you are getting in.

Sorry, incorrect cell! Simple =TEXT(5;"00")  works! Same with =TEXT(i4;"00") . But nothing  more complex which has a format included.

@mak ok, I understand not working. Show me a screenshot to understand the issue as simple as that. If TEXT() is what you use, then i have clearly shown a screenshot with the formula bar showing it is working on my end. what else can i show you to explain. Its on you who needs to validate, dont take offense but i have to understand the issue. without seeing how can i say. Formulas differ widely with different languages and custom formatting differ with regional settings!

@mak what about this one? --> Is this one still not working for you? =TEXT(ROUND(I4*2, 2), "€ 0.00") & " /pc // " & TEXT(ROUND(I4*2*E4, 2), "€ 0.00") & " /unit"

I got it done by =TEXT(J4*(1+$K$1);"€ 0,00") & "/pc  //  " & TEXT(J4*(1+$K$1)E4;"€ 0,00") & "/unit". But still not working is =TEXT(J4(1+$K$1);"€ #.##0,00") & "/pc  //  " & TEXT(J4*(1+$K$1)*E4;"€ #.##0,00") & "/unit". So a number larger than 999 would appear as "€ 1234,00" and not as "€ 1.234,00" as desired. Very strange as MS support has an example of   =TEXT(1234.567,"$#,##0.00") which also does not work, althought changed to =TEXT(1234,567,"$#.##0,00") (German setting)

It seems to be a problem with the punctuation in the TEXT formula.
